# Перевод на новую строку при переборе массива

Tags: python, циклы, вывод

При выводе результата print

```
def test_fun(SKU):
    for i in SKU:
        massive = "N'{}',".format(i)
        print(str(massive))
```

ковычка и запятая ( ', ) после результата из фигурных скобок переводится на другую строку

В таком виде:

N'994922
',

N'981308
',

Как  это победить ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ничего не переводится. Проверяй, что у тебя там в исходных данных.

Comment: В исходных данных , результат запроса из БД MSSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была не в коде.
Был указан не верный тип данных столбцов SQL SERVER.
После изменения типа

> с .nchar на .nvarchar

, всё заработало.
Всем спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Именно поэтому у Вас и спрашивали, какие данные приходят на вход, а не откуда они приходят. Достаточно увидеть изначальные данные и станет сразу понятно, почему оно форматирует их тем или иным образом.

Answer (score 0):

Можно предположить что так:

```
def test_fun(SKU):
    for i in SKU:
        massive = "N'{}',".format(i.strip('\n'))
        print(str(massive))
```

Comment: К сожалению это не помогло... Добавлю уточнение, что перевод на новую строку исчезает если я уберу какой либо символ после фигурных скобок.

Comment: Покажите ваши данные SKU

Comment: Лучше `strip()` без аргументов, тогда он по идее все пробельные символы удалить должен. Они разные могут быть. Хотя и это может не помочь.

Comment: @Rollmops сожалеть можно лишь о том, что вы не предоставили  `SKU`